# Should I store the entries submitted by anonymous users in the same table as registered users?

Tags: database-design

Sorry for long question. Let me tell you a bit about my database:

Right now I have two tables for users:

1. Table for registered users
2. Table for non-registered users (anonymous)

Those tables have exactly the same structure, they both have:

1. ID (primary, int)
2. Account ID (int, 0 for anonymous, registered users start with 1)
3. IP address
4. And other identical fields (create date, user action)

Only difference is, when I query the both tables:

1. I query the user entries the "non-registered" table by IP address (to differentiate them)
2. I query the user entries in the "registered" table by Account ID

This was a decision I made long time ago when I started my project. But now it seems like a very poor decision to me and I think it will create more problems.

I want to know if there is ANY benefit to having two separate tables in this situation. Or I could just have one table and add an extra field called "anonymous" (BIT type, true or false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you duplicate tables, you'll have to duplicate code too. A fix or a modification on your table need to be done twice.

Anyway, the good practice is to be DRY (don't repeat yourself). So, I recommand only one table.